# Pandas get binary count of co-occurrences within groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Alright, so this is one I've been puzzling over for a few days now.

Let's say I have some user interaction data in the following dataframe format:

```
user_id_a | user_id_b | time
     2          5       2017-12-12 14:00
     1          7       2017-12-12 14:20
     2          5       2017-12-12 14:40
     2          5       2017-12-13 11:00
     4          12      2017-12-15 9:00
```

I want the sum of a binary count of whether they interacted within a certain time frame...so for example, if the time frame was 1 day, I would want to end up with:

```
user_id_a | user_id_b | num_time_frames_seen_together
     2          5       2
     1          7       1
     4          12      1
```

Because in this case, although users 2 and 5 interacted 3 times total, 2 of those interactions were within the same time frame, so only one value was added their total.

I've gotten as far as:

```
df = df.set_index('time').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1D'))
```

Which essentially gives me my first example table. But I'm really at a loss as what to do next. I'm fairly new to Pandas, and while I know I could iterate through the rows and calculate this manually, I'm pretty sure there must be some sort of Pandas functionality with which I'm just not yet familiar.

Comment: How long is a time frame?  What if 2 and 4 had records 41 minutes apart would this still count as one?  At what time should it counts as two records?  different day?

Comment: and does order count are 2,5 and 5,2 added together?

Comment: In this example, a time frame is one day. And no, order shouldn't matter. But my data is always sorted such that the smallest value is in the user_id_a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the prettiest, but this will work, say, even when you have 2, 5 and 5, 2 (these should be counted as the same pair of people I'm assuming).

Once you call `groupby`, call `apply` + `value_counts`, to get a datewise count. You can then sum up across dates with `sum`.

```
df = df.set_index('time')\
       .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1D'))\
       .apply(lambda x: x.apply(frozenset, 1).value_counts() > 0)\
       .sum(level=1)
df

(2, 5)     2.0
(1, 7)     1.0
(4, 12)    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use `dt.floor` and `nunique`:

```
df.assign(day = df['time'].dt.floor('D')).groupby(['user_id_a','user_id_b'])['day'].nunique()\
  .reset_index(name='num_seen_together')
```

Output:

```
   user_id_a  user_id_b  num_seen_together
0          1          7                  1
1          2          5                  2
2          4         12                  1
```